# Inserir com "for" em uma lista encadeada

Tags: java, lista, lista-encadeada

Galera estou com uma duvida, o professor pediu para inserir elementos na lista encadeada usando o "for" mas estou com dificuldade, a Classe que cria o nó ja esta funcionando perfeitamente e a parte que eu consegui desenvolver foi isso mas esta dando nullPointException quando eu tento inserir do segundo elemento em diante.

```
public void inserir(Node novoNode){
        if(inicio == null){
            inicio = novoNode;
        } else {
            Node aux = inicio;
            for(int i = tamanho ; i < (tamanho +1) ; i++){
                aux = aux.getProximo();
             }
            aux.setProximo(novoNode);
        }
        tamanho ++;
}
```

Comment: Quem é "inicio"? Como você inicializa o tamanho? Quem chama o método inserir passando o novoNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está mesmo no próprio `for`. Ele deveria ter outra instrução de inicio assim como outra de fim. Desta forma:

```
//de 0 até ao tamanho - 1 para parar no ultimo
for(int i = 0; i < tamanho - 1; i++){  
    aux = aux.getProximo();
}
```

Códigos de listas são normalmente escritos com `while` e costumam executam até apanhar o fim da lista, o `null`. Mesmo com uma restrição de usar um `for` podemos usar a mesma lógica, o que simplifica:

```
else {
    Node aux;

    //escrito desta maneira fica sem conteúdo, servindo so para navegar até ao ultimo
    for(aux = inicio; aux.getProximo() != null ; aux = aux.getProximo());

    aux.setProximo(novoNode);
}
```

Neste ultimo exemplo começamos a navegar no `inicio`, e navegamos até que o próximo seja `null`, que é o caso de paragem. Quando o próximo é `null` significa que estamos no ultimo elemento que é onde queremos parar. Para cada navegação vamos andando para o próximo elemento com `aux = aux.getProximo();` como já era feito anteriormente.